# Python script run error QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console, nameerror

I have been using the Python console in QGIS to develop a script. However, I keep getting the below error whenever I try to execute it.

[image]

This is line 43 which has the error
[image]

Comment: Did you import QgsGraph?

Comment: I have tried but it gives me this error.

" line 2, in ImportError: cannot import name 'QgsGraph' from 'qgis.core' (C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.11/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\core\__init__.py) "

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure you are *correctly* importing the `QgsGraph` class. The first port of call should always be the official documentation.

Both the [Python](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.28/analysis/QgsGraph.html) and [C++ api](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGraph.html) docs show clearly that the `QgsGraph` class belongs to the `analysis` library so trying to import it from the `core` library won't work:

[image]

[image]

Therefore, the correct import statement is:

```py
from qgis.analysis import QgsGraph
```

Then you can create an instance and work with the class:

```py
graph = QgsGraph()
```